# Do not post a form in a Rails root route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rendering

I have a controller with just one method:

```
index_controller.rb

def index
  # some code
end
```

The form:

```
index.html.erb

<%= form_tag :class => "form-inline signup" do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :url, nil, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "URL do tópico" %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Enviar", method: :post, :class => 'btn btn-theme' %>
<% end %>
```

And a simple root route:

```
    root 'index#index'
    post '/', to: 'index#index'
```

The problem is that when I load the root page, the form is posted automatically, when the preferable was to POST just on the button call.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the code for the `post` out to another action that can handle that.

```
post '/', :to => "index#submit"
```

Then you can define a `submit` action within your `IndexController` to handle the form, and the `index` action won't run the form code anymore.

Comment: I knew that it was a small thing. Thanks Ryan.